# How to get the list of defined procedures from a class

Tags: delphi

I Define a Testclass like

```
MyTest = Class(TTestCLass)
  procedure DoMyTest_1 (...);
  procedure DoAnontherTest (...);
  function OnemoreTest : Boolean;
  .....
end;
```

Running Unit testing the testrunner framework shows the List of defined testfunctions and it is very easy to select individual test from the GUI / ListBox inside this framework. I would like to extract at run time the List of defined function from a class and be able to call this function dynamically.

The idea goes like this, but I do not know how to implement

```
procedure ExtractProcedureNamefromClass (aClass : TObject) : TStringlist ; 
begin
  ?????
end;

procedure ClassaClassProcedureByName ( aClass : TObject ; FunctionName : String );
begin
  ///  can you do it more flexible  
  if Functionname=DoMyTest_1 then 
    MyClass.DoMyTest_1(...);
end;
```

Comment: You can do this by using RTTI.

Comment: what is RTTL function

Comment: You can get a list of all method names by using [`RTTI`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending of your Delphi version you can use the [RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index).

like so

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  RTTI,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

var
 LCtx : TRttiContext;
 LMethod : TRttiMethod;
begin
  try
    LCtx:=TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      //list the methods for the TStrings class
      for LMethod in  LCtx.GetType(TStrings).GetMethods do
        Writeln(LMethod.Name);
    finally
      LCtx.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: It's just a matter of personal preference.